# Checking for alphabet and numeric chars in a field

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to write javascript code for making sure a field in my form has its first 2 characters as alphabets (US) and the rest 8 are numerics.

The total has to be 10, and if any of these are not satisfied, I should throw up an alert box.

I am checking for numerics now but I don't know how to combine checking for alphabets and numerics in the same field.

Here is my code for checking for numerics.

Please help me out! `sid` is my field name.

```
// only allow numbers to be entered
var checkOK = "0123456789";
var checkStr = document.forms[0].sid.value;
var allValid = true;
var allNum = "";

for (i = 0; i < checkStr.length; i++)
{
    ch = checkStr.charAt(i);
    for (j = 0; j < checkOK.length; j++)
        if (ch == checkOK.charAt(j))
            break;

    if (j == checkOK.length)
    {
        allValid = false;
        break;
        if (ch != ",")
            allNum += ch;
    }
    if (!allValid)
    {
        alert("Please enter only 8 numeric characters in the \"sid\" field.");
        return (false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not use Regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single regular expression will easily perform this check :

```
   /^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{8}$/
```

/^                      match beginning of string

[a-zA-Z]{2}          match exactly 2 alphabetic characters

\d{8}                match exactly 8 digits

$/                      match end of string

Use as follows :

```
 /^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{8}$/.test (str)   // Returns true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bjsyu/)

```
var regExp = /[a-z]{2}[0-9]{8}/i;

var text = 'ab12345678'; 
if(text .replace(/[a-z]{2}[0-9]{8}/i, "").length > 0){
    alert("Please enter only 8 numeric characters in the \"sid\" field.");
    return (false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regular expression, checks for 2 characters + 8 digits

```
var checkStr = document.forms[0].sid.value;
if (checkStr.match(/\b[A-z]{2}[0-9]{8}\b/) === null) {
    alert("Please enter only 8 numeric characters in the \"sid\" field.");
    return (false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`/^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{8})$/;` should check for 2 characters and then 8 decimals.